# Completion of a metric space alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space (that is not complete). Let $Y$ be the set of all Cauchy sequences in $X$. Define an equivalence relation on $Y$ by: $(a_1,a_2,...) \sim (b_1,b_2,...)$ if $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}d(a_k,b_k) = 0$; let $Z$ be the set of $Y's$ equivalence classes.

Define a metric $d_Z$ on $Z$ by $d_Z([(a_1,a_2,...)],[(b_1,b_2,...)]) = lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} d(a_k,b_k)$, where $[y]$ denotes the equivalence class of a Cauchy sequence $y$. It is not difficult to verify that $d_Z$ is a well-defined metric.

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3,...$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(Z,d_Z)$. Each $z_k$ is an equivalence class, so we can choose a Cauchy sequence $w_{k,1}, w_{k,2}, w_{k,3},...$ such that $[w_{k,1}, w_{k,2}, w_{k,3},...] = z_k$. Since $w_{k,1}, w_{k,2}, w_{k,3},...$ is Cauchy

$\exists N_k$ such that $m,n > N_k$ implies $d(w_{k,n},w_{k,m}) < \frac{1}{k}$.

We can define the sequence $w_{1,N_1},w_{2,N_2},w_{3,N_3},...$ . It is not too difficult to show that this sequence is Cauchy, so we can consider $[w_{1,N_1},w_{2,N_2},w_{3,N_3},...]$. My question is does $z_1,z_2,z_3,...$ converge to $[w_{1,N_1},w_{2,N_2},w_{3,N_3},...]$?

I know there are easier ways to show that $(Z,d_Z)$ is a completion of $(X,d_X)$ (e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Metric_Space)#Lemma_1:_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ-MathJax-29-QINU.60.22.27.7F_is_Well-Defined) but I just want to know if this way works.

Comment: Something seems amiss! I am not sure what exactly. But if you try to check the convergence, there may be some problem with the choice of $N_k$'s. I suggest you check it once again.

Comment: What is wrong with the $N_k$'s?

Comment: The problem is that you only know $m,n>N_k$ are close to each other not $m,n\geq N_k$.  So the $w_{k,N_k}$ need not be close to "limit" of $z_k$.

Comment: @user10354138 So do you think this approach is incorrect/a dead end?

Comment: No, you need to change the condition on $N_k$ to $m,n\geq N_k\Rightarrow d(w_{k,m},w_{k,n})<\frac1k$ instead of your original $m,n> N_k\Rightarrow d(w_{k,m},w_{k,n})<\frac1k$ if you want to use $(w_{k,N_k})_k$.

Comment: @user10354138 Okay, can you please give a hint on what to do next?